# firebase token has incorrect issuer claim

Tags: python, firebase, session, firebase-authentication, pyrebase

I am trying to create a simple flask app that will allow me to log in and out using Firebase but I am getting this error.

> Firebase ID token has incorrect "iss" (issuer) claim. Expected
> "https://securetoken.google.com/watering-web-app" but got
> "https://session.firebase.google.com/watering-web-app". Make sure the
> ID token comes from the same Firebase project as the service account
> used to authenticate this SDK. See
> https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens for
> details on how to retrieve ID token.

This is what the app.py file looks like for reference.

````
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
import firebase_admin
import pyrebase
from firebase_admin import credentials, auth

app = Flask(__name__)

# Firebase configuration
config = {
  "apiKey": "<API_KEY>",

    "databaseURL": "<DB_URL",
  
    "authDomain": "watering-web-app.firebaseapp.com",
  
    "projectId": "PROJECTID"
  
    "storageBucket": "BUCKET",
  
    "messagingSenderId": "ID",
  
    "appId": "APPID"
}

# Initialize Firebase app
firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
cred = credentials.Certificate('firebase-credentials.json')
firebaseAdmin = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

# Get a reference to the Firebase Authentication service
regAuth = firebase.auth()

# Home page
@app.route("/")
def home():
    # Get the Firebase ID token from the user's browser cookies.
    id_token = request.cookies.get('token')
    if id_token:
        try:
            # Verify the ID token and get the user's information.
            try:
                decoded_token = auth.verify_id_token(id_token)
                print(decoded_token)
                user_info = {
                    'uid': decoded_token['uid'],
                    'email': decoded_token.get('email', None),
                    #'name': decoded_token.get('name', None)
                }
                return render_template('home.html', user=user_info)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
    
        
        except auth.InvalidIdTokenError:
            # The token is invalid or expired. Redirect the user to the login page.
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
    
    # If there's no ID token, redirect the user to the login page.
    return redirect(url_for('login'))

# Sign up page
@app.route("/signup", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def signup():
    if request.method == "POST":
        # If the form was submitted, create a new user with the provided email and password
        email = request.form["email"]
        password = request.form["password"]
        try:
            regAuth.create_user_with_email_and_password(email, password)
            # If the user was created successfully, redirect to the login page
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        except:
            # If there was an error creating the user, render the signup page with an error message
            message = "An error occurred. Please try again."
            return render_template("signup.html", message=message)
    else:
        # If the user has not submitted the form, render the signup page
        return render_template("signup.html")

# Login page
@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        # If the form was submitted, authenticate the user with the provided email and password
        email = request.form["email"]
        password = request.form["password"]
        try:
            user = regAuth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email, password)
            # If the user was authenticated successfully, set a session cookie and redirect to the home page
            session_cookie = auth.create_session_cookie(user['idToken'], expires_in=36000)
            response = redirect(url_for('home'))
            response.set_cookie('token', session_cookie, httponly=True, secure=True)
            return response
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            
            # If there was an error authenticating the user, render the login page with an error message
            message = "Invalid email or password. Please try again."
            return render_template("login.html", message=message)
    else:

        # If the user has not submitted the form, render the login page
        return render_template("login.html")

# Logout route
@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    # Clear the session cookie and redirect to the login page
    response = redirect(url_for('login'))
    response.set_cookie('session', expires=0)
    return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)```

The error is happening in the home page when I try to decode the tokenId.<br>
`decoded_token = auth.verify_id_token(id_token)`
````

Answer (score 1):

I have found an answer.
The issue was that it should be `verify_session_cookie` not `verify_id_token`.
So the line in question now looks like this
`decoded_token = auth.verify_session_cookie(id_token)`